# get sum of the column for each different table javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I have a page where several tables displayed with the data from the backend with `php foreach` functionality. 
Each table has few rows with a column " m<sup>3</sup> "

```
<td  class="p-0 singleUnitCubic-{{$container->id}}">
          {{$item->prettyDecimal('total_cubic')}}
</td>
```

rendered result is:

```
_______________________________________________________
<td class="p-0 singleUnitCubic-13">
                    12.600
</td>
<td class="p-0 singleUnitCubic-13">
                    4.000
</td>
_______________________________________________________
Total:  <span id="totalCubic-13">16.600</span>


_______________________________________________________
<td class="p-0 singleUnitCubic-69">
                    4.230
</td>
<td class="p-0 singleUnitCubic-69">
                    3.000
</td>
_______________________________________________________
Total:  <span id="totalCubic-69">7.230</span>
```

Now I can easily get the sum for one of the tables because I marked each `class="singleUnitCubic"` with corresponding table id number, in this case, it's `class="singleUnitCubic-13"` and my sum function is:

```
cubicOutput = document.getElementById('totalCubic-13');

var sumSingleUnits = 0;

$('.singleUnitCubic-13').each(function(){
    sumSingleUnits += parseFloat($(this).text());
    cubicOutput.innerText = SingleUnits.toFixed(3);
});
```

but how can I do the same dynamically for other tables where `class="singleUnitCubic-69"` and also display that sum under each corresponding table where `<span id="totalCubic-69">`?

Should it be something like finding what is the `id` number after `singleUnitCubic-` which I could do by:

```
 <td onload="getTableid(this.class)"  class="p-0 singleUnitCubic-{{$container->id}}">
                    {{$item->prettyDecimal('total_cubic')}}
 </td>

function getTableId(Id) {
           tableId = Id.split('-')[1];
           totalCubic = document.getElementById("totalCubic-".concat(tableId));
```

and then somehow injecting it to the sum function?

P.S. I can't do the sum in back-end which would be easy.

Comment: You are getting sum on click of some button ?

Comment: nope, it's calculated when page loads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First determine the tables that have the target columns, you can use `:has()` or other method. Then iterate through each table and find the total. `Array#reduce` comes in handy here:

```
  //capture the table that have target columns
  const tables = $('table:has(td[class*=singleUnitCubic])');
  //now process each table
  const totals = tables.each(function() {
      //determine the id of span to update
      const id = ['#totalCubic',$('td[class*=singleUnitCubic]',this).attr('class').split(' ')
      .filter(c => c.indexOf('singleUnitCubic') === 0)[0]
      .split('-')[1]].join('-');
      //get this total
      const total = $('td[class*=singleUnitCubic]', this)
      .map((i,td) => +td.textContent).get()
      .reduce((acc, cur) => acc += cur, 0);
      //now update the dom
      $(id).text( total.toFixed(3) );
  });
```

**DEMO**

```js
$(function() {
  //capture the table that have target columns
  const tables = $('table:has(td[class*=singleUnitCubic])');
  //now process each table
  const totals = tables.each(function() {
      //determine the id of span to update
      const id = ['#totalCubic',$('td[class*=singleUnitCubic]',this).attr('class').split(' ')
      .filter(c => c.indexOf('singleUnitCubic') === 0)[0]
      .split('-')[1]].join('-');
      //get this total
      const total = $('td[class*=singleUnitCubic]', this)
      .map((i,td) => +td.textContent).get()
      .reduce((acc, cur) => acc += cur, 0);
      //now update the dom
      $(id).text( total.toFixed(3) );
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="p-0 singleUnitCubic-13">
                    12.600
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="p-0 singleUnitCubic-13">
                    4.000
</td>
</tr></tbody>
</table>
Total:  <span id="totalCubic-13"></span>


<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="p-0 singleUnitCubic-69">
                    4.230
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="p-0 singleUnitCubic-69">
                    3.000
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
Total:  <span id="totalCubic-69"></span>
```

**Determining the ID for the Total**

```
//just a way to concatenate strings ['totalCubic', '69'].join('-')
//to give rise to 'totalCubic-69'
//for example
```

In this version of the demo I have broken down the line determining the total `id` into several lines just to make it simpler to follow what is being done:

```
  //get class(es) of first td of this table as an array
  const cl = $('td[class*=singleUnitCubic]',this).attr('class').split(' ');
  console.log( cl );
  //But we only need one 'singleUnitCubic-' ....
  const onecl = cl.filter(c => c.indexOf('singleUnitCubic') === 0)[0];
  console.log( onecl );
  //And we just want to numeric part at the end
  const thenumber = onecl.split('-')[1];
  //So now the id where the total will be put is
  const id = ['#totalCubic', thenumber].join('-');
  //or const id = `#totalCubic-${thenumber}`;
```

```js
$(function() {
  //capture the table that have target columns
  const tables = $('table:has(td[class*=singleUnitCubic])');
  //now process each table
  const totals = tables.each(function() {
      //get class(es) of first td of this table as an array
      const cl = $('td[class*=singleUnitCubic]',this).attr('class').split(' ');
      console.log( cl );
      //But we only need one 'singleUnitCubic-' ....
      const onecl = cl.filter(c => c.indexOf('singleUnitCubic') === 0)[0];
      console.log( onecl );
      //And we just want to numeric part at the end
      const thenumber = onecl.split('-')[1];
      //So now the id where the total will be put is
      const id = ['#totalCubic', thenumber].join('-');
      //or const id = `#totalCubic-${thenumber}`;
      /*determine the id of span to update
      const id = ['#totalCubic',$('td[class*=singleUnitCubic]',this).attr('class').split(' ')
      .filter(c => c.indexOf('singleUnitCubic') === 0)[0]
      .split('-')[1]].join('-');*/
      //get this total
      const total = $('td[class*=singleUnitCubic]', this)
      .map((i,td) => +td.textContent).get()
      .reduce((acc, cur) => acc += cur, 0);
      //now update the dom
      $(id).text( total.toFixed(3) );
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="p-0 singleUnitCubic-13">
                    12.600
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="p-0 singleUnitCubic-13">
                    4.000
</td>
</tr></tbody>
</table>
Total:  <span id="totalCubic-13"></span>


<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="p-0 singleUnitCubic-69">
                    4.230
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="p-0 singleUnitCubic-69">
                    3.000
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
Total:  <span id="totalCubic-69"></span>
```

Comment: thanks, this works. Now I have to study why it works and especially what is this `const id = ['#totalCubic',$('td[class*=singleUnitCubic]',this).attr('class').split(' ')`

Comment: Study, is the right way to go. You can't go wrong with that. I have added a second demo to explain that particular line. See if it helps in any way.

Answer (score 1):

When making your td element you could take the id out of your classes and make it it's own attribute using [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes).

Something like this:

```
<td  data-table-id={{$container->id}} class="p-0 singleUnitCubic">
  {{$item->prettyDecimal('total_cubic')}}
</td>
```

Then change your total to have the same attribute. Also change it's id to a class.

```
Total:  <span data-table-id={{$container->id}} class="totalCubic">16.600</span>
```

Then you can get a node list of of all your totalCubic elements. Loop over it and pass each singleUnitCubic with matching data-table-id attribute to your sum function. Then update totalCubic.

Here's a [working JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/Lf3jp5wn/17/).

Comment: Thanks for the code, I see what you did and understand what's where, but for some reason, I always get 0 in `<div>Total: <span data-table-id="dogs" class="totalCubic"></span></div>`

Comment: @SPL You probably don't have a table with the id "dogs". I used that id in the fiddle as an example that the id can be anything, so long as it matches. You should set the `data-table-id` attribute using your `$icontainer->id` like in the second code snippet of my post.

Comment: sorry I forgot to change dogs to the id number in the comment, still checking why it doesnt want to work

Comment: @SPL Did you copy/paste the JS code from my fiddle? If so then the line `const units = document.querySelectorAll('div[data-table-id="' + id +'"]')` is probably causing the issue. It's searching for a `div` element, which is what's in my example. You'll need to change that to `td` for your code.